# Is Android Bluetooth scanning delivering cached/buffered results through onScanResult callback?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I am developing some BLE related applications for a while.
The doubt is simple, "Is the BLE scan results we receiving with `android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback`'s `onScanResult` method providing a cached set of results?"

If you are not getting me clearly, please let me explain a little more by diving into my experiments.

I am using Beacons from [Pinmicro (Card Beacon)](https://pinmicro.com/en/beaconplus-hardware.html) and we configured it to broadcast/advertise at an interval of 100 ms.
I'm using the `android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY` mode for starting the scan, and ofcourse I'm running it in android versions above Lolipop (Nexus 5 with 6.0.1, to be precise). I'm having around 100 beacons around me, but logging only one beacon (say TARGET beacon) along with its RSSI in the logcat.

So, when I starts the scan, things are almost okay for 2-3 minutes, but going further the RSSI updates are getting a bit delayed. See the below scenario:

1. Start scan
2. Place the TARGET beacon close to Nexus 5 - Getting RSSI around -30 to -40
3. Place the TARGET beacon a bit away from Nexus 5 - Getting RSSI around -60 to -70
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 a number of times, waiting 30 seconds in between each cycle
5. After 15 or 20 cycles I'm getting RSSI -60 to -70 on step 2 and RSSI -30 to -40 on step 3.

What I'm assuming is that, Android OS is caching all the BLE advertisments and dispatching these cached results through `onScanResult` callback and this results in delivering old cached advertisments to be deliverd after few seconds. I'm not sure, but will it be the case? If so, is there any way to clear the BLE advertisment cache from OS?

Any sort of suggestions are most welcomed, like direct methods to clear the cache, work arounds, reflection techniques,etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get to the root cause of delayed BLE scan callback results from the OS?

Comment: @madking I was doing some complex processing inside the 'onScanResult' callback itself. I read somewhere that it will be better to move that processing code to a separate thread instead of doing it all from the same thread, which may cause a delay in completing the callback and returning. With some proper threading implementation, the issue is no longer exist in my code. But tested in new phones only, with version Android N and above.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no cache. As long as your app process them fast enough there will be no delay (otherwise they get queued up).

Comment: I'm simply printing the log in logcat, in a separate thread using an instance of `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` from the `onScanResult` callback.